# Dynamically Build Q Filter in Django, with AND and OR Operators?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a database table of articles which includes a field `link`, which is the link to the article.

I'd like to filter for articles in a given date range, that come from domains in a given list.

I've got a string array like this:

```
domain_names = [
    'domain_name_1',
    'domain_name_2',
    'domain_name_3',
    'domain_name_4',
]
```

...and I have a filter like this which works:

```
data = (myArticles.objects
    .filter(Q(creation_datetime__range=[from_date, to_date]) & (Q(link__contains=domain_names[0]) | Q(link__contains=domain_names[1]) | Q(link__contains=domain_names[2]) | Q(link__contains=domain_names[3])))
    )
```

I'd like to dynamically build the filter, so that if an object is added to or removed from the `domain_names` list, the filter will dynamically update.

I've tried this:

```
q_object = Q()
    for name in domain_names:
        q_object.add(Q(link__contains=name), Q.OR)

    q_object = q_object.add(Q(creation_datetime__range=[from_date, to_date]), Q.AND)
```

...but I'm getting back all the objects in the date range, and the filter that's supposed to be filtering on domain_names isn't doing anything yet.

What's the correct way to dynamically build a Q filter in this case?

Comment: Think you need to add `q_object = ...` in your for loop, otherwise you're creating a new Q but not assigning it to anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work with:

```
q_object = Q(
    *[Q(link__contains=name) for name in domain_names],
    _connector=Q.OR
)
```

and then retrieve data with:

```
data = myArticles.objects.filter(
    q_object,
    creation_datetime__range=(from_date, to_date)
)
```

Comment: This works: ```data = myArticles.objects.filter(creation_datetime__range=(from_date, to_date))```. And this works: ```data = myArticles.objects.filter(q_object)```. But this: ```data = myArticles.objects.filter(q_object, creation_datetime__range=(from_date, to_date))```  ...returns an empty set. What am I missing?

Comment: Well it means that for the given timestamp range, there are no `myArticles` with at least one of the keywords, it is thus possible that there are `myArticle`s with the given keyword(s), but not in the time range.